# RestSharp - Serialize list without parent element

Tags: xml-serialization, restsharp

I've seen similar questions on SO about this, but this is specifically about RestSharp XmlSerializer.

I want this:

```
<Item>
    ...
</Item>
<Item>
    ...
</Item>
<Item>
    ...
</Item>
<Item>
    ...
</Item>
```

I have this:

```
public class MyPoco
{
    [SerializeAs( Name = "Item")
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    ...
}
```

What I'm getting is this:

```
<Item>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
    <Item>
        ...
    </Item>
</Item>
```

How do I get rid of the  parent element when using RestSharp?

Comment: Just a side note: an XML document must have exactly one root element, i.e. what you want is not strictly valid XML. I don't know about RestSharp, but perhaps it won't allow rendering invalid XML.

Comment: To be clear this is just the xml fragment I've posted. There is of course one root element.

Answer (score 2):

Change SerializeAs to XmlElement:

```
[XmlElement("Item")]
public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Then tell RestSharp to use the .NET serializer:

```
 var request = new RestRequest
 {              
     XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer(),
 };
```

This will output your list of Items without the parent Item node

Answer (score 1):

That will help:

```
public class MyPoco : List<Item> {}

public class Item { ... }
```

Comment: Inheriting from list is not reccomended.  See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt)

Comment: @Almenon why it is not recommended in this case? You should read your link better.

Comment: I did read it.  But you're right, I should be more specific.  Inheriting from a list is not reccomended for buisiness objects, but if it is a mechanism then that is fine.